# mysql_real_escape_string distorts user input - how to fix

Tags: php, mysql-real-escape-string

I have all my inputs from the user (that end up in a mysql table) go through `mysql_real_escape_string()` per php.net and most forum users.  I honestly don't know what it does internally.

What I do know is that running on my xampp light installation it does not effect the user input, but when I upload to my production Linux server it adds a '\' to the user input whenever the user uses an apostrophe such that `It's` becomes `It\'s`.

What is the fix for this?

Comment: Please show us the code.

Comment: I'll do it and I might add that magic quotes is a good name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have [`magic_quotes`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) enabled on your remote server. [Disable it](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).